# piping files in unix for "wc" while retaining filename

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, pipe

I have a bunch of files of the form `myfile[somenumber]` that are in nested directories.

I want to generate a line count on each of the files, and output that count to a file.

These files are binary and so they have to be piped through an additional script `open_file` before they can be counted by "wc".  I do:

```
ls ~/mydir/*/*/other_dir/myfile* | while read x; do open_file $x | wc -l; done > stats
```

this works, but the problem is that it outputs the line counts to the file `stats` without saying the original filename. for example, it outputs:

```
100
150
```

instead of:

```
/mydir/...pathhere.../myfile1: 100
/mydir/...pathhere.../myfile2: 150
```

**Second question:**

What if I wanted to divide the number of `wc -l` by a constant, e.g. dividing it by 4, before outputting it to the file?

I know that the number of lines is a multiple of 4 so the result should be in an integer. Not sure how to do that from the above script.

how can I make it put the original filename and the `wc -l` result in the output file?

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can output the file name before counting the lines:
`echo -n "$x: " ; open_file $x | wc -l`. The `-n` parameter to `echo` omits the trailing newline in the output.

To divide integers, you can use `expr`, e.g., `expr $(open_file $x | wc -l) / 4`.

So, the complete while loop will look as follows:

```
while read x; do echo -n "$x: " ; expr $(open_file $x | wc -l) / 4 ; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
while read x; do echo -n "$x: " ; s=$(open_file $x | wc -l); echo $(($s / 4));
```

You've thrown away the filename by the time you get to `wc(1)` -- all it ever sees is a `pipe(7)` -- but you *can* echo the filename yourself before opening the file. If `open_file` fails, this will leave you with an ugly output file, but it might be a suitable tradeoff.

The `$((...))` uses `bash(1)` arithmetic expansion. It might not work on your shell.